# What are the different options for running code at a specified time in iOS?

Tags: ios

What are the different options for running code on an iOS device at a specified time while the app is in the background? So far I have found that I could possibly use a Timer object, use the Grand Central Dispatch timer, and use CloudKit Push Notification with the Apple Push Notification service.

Any ideas are welcome. I'm having a hard time finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the apple documentation for [background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Here is the apple documentation for the [execution states](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) of an application.

You should understand a few things:

- When an app moves into the background you have a very small amount of time (3 minutes approximately) to execute finite-length tasks.
- If your application is not running, you could use a notification to wake the application. This requires the user to take an action and will make the application active.
- You can also wake an application with a local notification, it doesn't have to be a remote notification.
- The code that you want to run really needs to fall into one of the blessed scenarios that apple defines otherwise you run the risk of being deprioritized or ignored entirely.
- A block of code scheduled to run with a Timer or GCD will not be invoked while the application is in the background.

Roughly, you should register a background execution mode and follow the guidelines I linked above and while your application is backgrounded the application will be given time to execute code.

Comment: I actually need the code to run while the app is in the background or take the app to the foreground then run the code at any time, not just 3 minutes before the app goes in the background.

I read in another stack overflow post that the app will be taken to the foreground only by a remote notification, as opposed to a local notification.

Comment: I've seen an app in App Store that is able to play music when the notification fires. It's music longer than the 30 seconds that Apple limits to a sound of a notification. I don't know how they do it, but they do it. The notification doesn't take the app out of the background, it plays the music even when the device is locked.

Comment: This is incorrect, a user can open the application in response to a local notification, read the discussion documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622930-application?language=objc

Comment: You can easily ask for the ability to play audio in the background, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26, which is different from playing audio in response to a notification

Comment: I need the audio to play at a specified time before the user interacts with the device in any way. I'm creating an alarm clock.

Comment: Here is an example of creating an alarm clock, from the background execution document that I have already linked, using local notifications, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW31

Comment: Yes. That works. However, I need the audio to play longer than 30 seconds. The sound property of the UNNotificationContent object that you set when you set up the notification request has a 30 second limit.

Comment: I have an app on my iPhone from the App Store that is able to play audio (longer than 30 seconds) when a notification appears on the lock screen. I think the code to play the audio is located in the app instead of in the notification extension, but I can't tell. I've also tried to figure out how to play the audio from the app extension, but there is no place to put code that runs when the notification fires, before the user interacts with the notification.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've figured out how to play the music in the background if the music starts while the app is in the foreground, but I need the music to start playing while the app is in the background at any time, not just within 3 minutes of the app going into the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184430/discussion-between-michael-reneer-and-shinehahgnolaum).